# java.lang.RuntimeException в android

Tags: java, android

Привет, в одном старом приложении на Андроид через систему firebase начали поступать претензии с ошибкой, добиться которых ни на реальных ни на виртуальных устройствах я не могу уже месяц, ошибка эта приходит строго раз в сутки в 8 вечера по Киеву, но возможно это так сам сервис шлет.

Как я понимаю это связано с тем что у меня куча одновременно показанных картинок в самом приложении, и таким образом кончается память, так как раньше была такая проблема, но отчетов по ней уже очень давно не было, сразу как я порывшись в гугле вроде бы как ее исправил

В отчете firebase также говорится что затронут всего 1 человек, то есть я так понимаю что у него или же специфический аппарат, либо он один кто активно пользуется приложением.

Я уже перепробовал все что смог понять из первых страниц гугла, но как вижу не сработало, очень надеюсь что кто-то сможет подсказать куда копать, или же как добиться такой же ошибки у себя!

В файле:
ViewRootImpl.java

Сам сток ошибки:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Adding window failed at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:746) at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java) Caused by:
>   android.os.TransactionTooLargeException: at
>   android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java) at
>   android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:710)
>   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:735) at
>   android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:278)
>   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3064)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2394)
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Согласно вот этому ответу на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12809171/3212712) `TransactionTooLargeException` может быть, действительно, вызвана нехваткой памяти.

Лечить можно сократив объём инфы, передаваемой меж частями приложения. Например не передавая много картинок меж активити через `Bundle`. Другие варианты есть по ссылке в начале ответа

Comment: Логично будет попробовать отловить ошибку, запустив приложение на виртуалке и выделить ей мало памяти.

Comment: Xoxole > Пробовал, не получилось, просто тормозит и все...

ЮрийСПб > а возможен вариант что старые активности не выгружаются из памяти и таким образом забивают память?